# how to avoid the potential of an overflow when computing an average of times?

Tags: c++, winapi, average

I am writing a function for getting the average of the clocks it takes to call a specific `void (*)(void)` aka `void -> void` function a specific number of times.

I am worried that it if the sample size gets too large, the sum of the observations will overflow and make the average invalid.

is there a standard approach to removing the possibility of sum overflowing in these kinds of problems?

Note: I understand that this example is too naive to conclude anything about performance; I am interested eliminating the possibility of sum overflow, not concluding anything performance wise.

Note2: I also understand that a 64 bit unsigned number will not realistically overflow unless the program is run for hundreds of years, but I am curious if it is possible to eliminate this assumption too.

Here is my self contained code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * i want to parametrize the type which is used to store sample size
 * to see whether it impacts performance 
 */
template <typename sampleunit_t>
static inline ULONGLONG AveragePerformanceClocks (void (*f)(),  sampleunit_t nSamples)
{
    ULONGLONG sum;
    sampleunit_t i;    

    sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nSamples; ++i) {
        LARGE_INTEGER t1; 
        LARGE_INTEGER t2;
        ULONGLONG dt;

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
        f();        
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

        dt = t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart;

        // sum may possibly overflow if program runs long enough with
        // a large enough nSamples
        sum += dt;
    }


    return (ULONGLONG)(sum / nSamples);
}

/* a cdecl callback that consumes time */
static void test1() 
{
    // don't optimize
    volatile int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {

    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ULONGLONG avg;

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<BYTE>(test1, 255);    
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);   

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<WORD>(test1, 255);    
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);   

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<DWORD>(test1, 255);    
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);   

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<ULONGLONG>(test1, 255);    
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);   

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your calculations are off. The value will only realistically overflow, if the function runs for hundreds of thousands of years. This is not an issue to worry about. If you are concerned about integer overflows in general, you should ask that question. It'll make for a way shorter [mcve], too.

Comment: See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663116/how-to-calculate-average-of-int64-t/56663458?noredirect=1#comment99895704_56663458

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The average of the first n elements is

```
          SUM
Average = ---
           n
```

The next element Mi is

```
           (SUM + Mi)
Average2 = ----------
              n + 1
```

So given the current average, it is possible to find the next average with the new reading.

```
           (Average * n + Mi )
Average2 = -------------------
                  n + 1
```

This can then be changed to an equation which doesn't increase

```
                       n      Mi
Average2 = Average * ----- + -----
                     n + 1   n + 1
```

In practice for timing, the size of time will fit within the datatype of the computer.

As pointed out, this needs to use a floating point representation, and whilst will not fail due to overflow, can still fail when `n/(n+1)` is smaller than the accuracy of the floating point fraction part.

### Update

From [incremental average](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/calculating-the-average-incrementally/)

There is a better reorganization.

```
                       Mi - Average
Average2 = Average  +  -------------
                           n + 1
```

It is better, because it only has one division.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this result in additional truncation unless average is performed using floating points? I'm starting to think this might be unsolvable for even two samples without switching to signed times to correct overflows; and both float and integer approaches can get cumulative truncation errors.

Comment: I think this might be the only solution; calculate the average as a double internally.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce potential for overflow by adding to `sum` the value `dt/nSamples` while making sure that you don't lose `dt%nSamples`.

```
template <typename sampleunit_t>
static inline ULONGLONG AveragePerformanceClocks (void (*f)(),
                                                  sampleunit_t nSamples)

{
    ULONGLONG delta = 0;
    ULONGLONG sum = 0;
    sampleunit_t i;    

    for (i = 0; i < nSamples; ++i) {
        LARGE_INTEGER t1; 
        LARGE_INTEGER t2;
        ULONGLONG dt;

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
        f();        
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

        dt = t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart;

        // Reduce the potential for overflow.
        delta += (dt%nSamples);
        sum += (dt/nSamples);
        sum += (delta/nSamples);
        delta = (delta%nSamples);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent an overflow of a sum value in a calculation, you can normalize the base values:

Let's say that your input is data is:

```
20
20
20
20
20
```

The `sum` would be 100, the `average` 20 and the `count` 5.

If now a new value, 30, would be added and I would be using a 7 bits integer as value to store the `sum` in, you would hit the overflow and have an issue.

The trick is to normalize:

1. Take the new value, 30,  and divide it by the `average` value, let's call it `new_val_norm`
2. Take the `average` value and divide it by the `average` (so 1.000), and multiply by the `count`, let's call this `avg_norm`
3. Add the new value `new_val_norm` to the `avg_norm` value, divide by the `count`+1 (we just added one extra value), and multiply by `average` to get the new avg value.

The risk of overflow is then pushed away for the sum since it is just not used anymore.

If the avg * count (`avg_norm`) is still to large, you can also opt to divide the new value by avg and count, and adding 1 to that.

Answer (score -2):

If you have an estimate for your mean you can reduce the likelyhood of an overflow, the more precise your estimate to the real mean the less likely an overflow will occur.

The following uses as estimate the average of the previous call (except for the first, where 0 is chose, which equals the idiomatic averaging function).

Of course this is no fool-proof way to avoid an overflow either.

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * i want to parametrize the type which is used to store sample size
 * to see whether it impacts performance
 */
template <typename sampleunit_t>
static inline ULONGLONG
AveragePerformanceClocks (void (*f)(), ULONGLONG estimate, sampleunit_t nSamples)
{
    LONGLONG sum;
    sampleunit_t i;

    sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < nSamples; ++i) {
        LARGE_INTEGER t1;
        LARGE_INTEGER t2;
        ULONGLONG dt;

        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
        f();
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);

        dt = t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart;

        // sum may possibly overflow if program runs long enough with
        // a large enough nSamples
        sum += dt - estimate;
    }


    return estimate + (LONGLONG)(sum / nSamples);
}

/* a cdecl callback that consumes time */
static void test1()
{
    // don't optimize
    volatile int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {

    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ULONGLONG avg;

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<BYTE>(test1, 0, 255);
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<WORD>(test1, avg, 255);
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<DWORD>(test1, avg, 255);
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);

    avg = AveragePerformanceClocks<ULONGLONG>(test1, avg, 255);
    printf("average clocks(truncated): %llu.\n", avg);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```