# How to calculate average of int64_t

Tags: c++, math, average, mean

I need to calculate the average of n numbers. N is unknown at compile time. Each of the numbers could be an int64_t type but I know that also average fits in int64_t type. Problem is that the sum of n numbers could be too large for int64_t.
Any suggestions?

Comment: use an int128_t?

Comment: [try this incremental approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765087/how-to-avoid-the-potential-of-an-overflow-when-computing-an-average-of-times)

Comment: @TarickWelling: There is no such type in the standard, and even if it were, it wouldn't really answer the question (which, I admit, should probably have been phrased in terms of `intmax_t`). Now, if you would turn that link into an answer, *that* would be helpful...

Comment: you didn't specify your platform or compiler so: GCC and CLANG do support a non standard variant of the 128 bit int. But I think I would prefer the incremental approach

Comment: gcc also has __builtin_add_overflow which will tell you if an overflow occurs, which might also help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Average of two nos without overflow

```
  Average = (a / 2) + (b / 2) + (((a % 2) + (b % 2)) / 2)
```

This can be extended to n numbers as well.

Suppose you have n numbers from N1, N2....Nn-1, Nn

```
Average = (N1 / n) + (N2 / n) +.....+ (Nn-1 / n) + (Nn / n)

                            +

          ((N1 % n) + (N2 % n) +.....+ (Nn-1 % n) + (Nn % n)) / n
```

Comment: nicely done, I was just about to suggest a more complicated approach based on the same idea

Comment: Interesting solution. It does however require you to know `n` in advance of feeding in the _first_ number but if you do then this works well.

Comment: is there a way to refer this answer to the question others suggested in the comments to the OP? I feel this is a much better answer than the one provided there

Comment: Careful, if `n` is big, there may be a corner case where `((N1 % n) + (N2 % n) +.....+ (Nn-1 % n) + (Nn % n))` overflows.

Comment: @NO_NAME N would have to be > 2^32 for that, I think this serves most cases, if someone needs, I believe I can come up with an algorithm that can support a theoretically infinite N (not known beforehand)